# Laravel transaction not rolling back on Stripe exception

Tags: php, exception, laravel, transactions

I need to rollback a transaction if anything goes wrong during a Stripe charge. I'm forcing an exception by removing the Stripe token, just to test the rollback. For some reason, the exception is being caught but the transaction does not rollback. I'm using Laravel 4.2 and MySQL 5.6. My tables are all InnoDB. Has anybody ran into this problem?

```
DB::beginTransaction();

// create order.
try
{
   // this function writes to two tables: orders and items
   $totals = $this->doOrder();
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
   DB::rollback();
   $this->logError($e);
   return Redirect::back()->with('danger', 'An error occurred while saving your order. Your card has not been charged.');
}

// Charge user's credit card.
try 
{
   \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(Config::get('stripe.secret_key'));

   $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
      'amount'      => ($totals['grand_total'] * 100),
      'currency'    => 'usd',
      'description' => Auth::user()->email_address,
      'source'      => ''  //<-- force exception by removing Stripe token
   ]);
} 
catch(\Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest $e)
{
   DB::rollback();
   $this->logError($e);
   return Redirect::back()->with('danger', 'An error occurred while processing your payment. Your card has not been charged.');
}

// If we made it this far, all is good and we can commit.
DB::commit();
```

Comment: Does it rolls back on the first `try-catch`?

Comment: Yes, if a MySQL exception is thrown, it rolls back. The problem is when an exception is thrown by Stripe in the second try-catch.

Comment: Can you verify if `\Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest` really catches the error?

Comment: yeah, the error gets logged and it redirects back with the message in the catch block, so that would indicate that it must have called the rollback function. I've been trying to figure this out for like two days now...

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question here, in case someone else runs into a similar problem.
The problem was caused by a stored procedure being executed in the doOrder() function shown in my sample code. The stored procedure executed certain statements that committed any pending changes at that point, so by the time a rollback was issued in Laravel, the changes were already committed.

I fixed this problem by ditching the stored procedure approach and rewriting that logic in PHP (Laravel) so everything happens in one place.